# How to test a spring component with multiple dependencies?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit

Trying to write some junits for a component. The issue im having is that that component has an autowired dependency, which itself has 3 autowired dependencies. So when I try to test a method, I keep getting a npe.

```
@Component
public class Transformer {
  private CacheService cacheService;
  
  public Transformer(CacheService cacheService) {
    this.cacheService = cacheService;
  }

  public void doAction(CustomObject o){
     cacheService.perform(o);
  }
```

```
@Component
public class CacheService {
  @Autowired private GenericBean genericBean;
  @Autowired private Dao dao
 
  public void doAction(CustomObject o){
   dao.fetch(o);
  }
}
```

Once it gets to that doAction method i get a npe since all those autowired beans are null. How do I get past this issue? I've tried a few past solutions I saw here, but none worked.

Comment: You should avoid field injection, it is possible - spring has mechanism of reflection to do it, but general rule is:

mandatory dependencies - use constructor injection;
optional dependencies - use setter injection;
field injection - avoid them;

Answer (score 0):

Consider using constructor level injection instead of field level injection (@Autowired on fields). Then you can construct your CacheService with needed mocks. this is best practice in most cases.
Otherwise check Spring @InjectMocks annotation.